# How to model probability of a web click using bayesian modelling with constraints?

Tags: bayesian

I'm trying to model clicks in a Google AdWords campaigns.  This is a function of impressions, the probability of a click (CTR) on that impression, the cost per click (CPC), and the budget of the advertiser.  It's essentially

$$\text{clicks} = \text{impressions}  \times \text{CTR}$$

subject to

$$\text{impressions} \times \text{CPC} \times \text{CTR} \leq \text{Budget}$$

**How should this constraint be incorporated into my model?**

Happy to provide more info if it'd be helpful.

Comment: What are your unknowns? Do you know CTR, CPC etc?

Comment: Every variable is random, but can be observed.

(BTW, using this model to play with PyMC after reading your IPython book - it's great, thanks)

Comment: so if you are interested in using PyMC, there is a Potential decorator that can be used for arbitrary constraints. Think of it as a multiplicative factor in your Prior. A decorator returns log-probabilities: it could return 0 if the constraint is satisfied, and -inf (`-np.inf`) if not satisfied.